# Calculate age in Oracle/Toad - using values from two columns

Tags: oracle, datediff, toad, floor, to-date

I have two Oracle columns (in a VIEW, not a table) - DateOfBirth and MembershipDate. I am trying to create a new column that will show the age of the person on the date that they took up the membership.

**Sample columns:**
**DateOfBirth:** 01/05/1975
**MembershipDate:** 01/09/2015
**AgeWhenBecameMemb:** 40

How do I get the third column to get calculated on the fly, please?

I'm looking to implement it using something like this:

> SELECT FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE '2012-01-01', DATE '2010-10-10')/12) AS AgeWhenBecameMemb from DUAL

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting ?  The formula seems to work fine for me ?  (might be your date format when you use `DATE '2012-01-01'` ... try putting the column names in there, or using `to_date()` function

Comment: Yes, the above code works. However, my date values are in DD/MM/YYYY - this format is not accepted. :(

Comment: L : .. ok ... so are you going to let us know what is accepted, and what you need? or do we have to keep guessing?  O.o  You might want to reconsider re-writing your question .. it clearly asks "how do I get the third column to get calculated on the fly" .. that's been answered .. however, I get the impression that's not the question you wanted to answer ...  O.o

Answer (score 0):

which version of Oracle?

In Oracle 11 or later, you have virtual columns: check this out: `https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:676611400346196844` ...

prior to that, you could consider a view, or materialized view - depending on other needs you have.

Comment: Oracle 12.1. I am creating a view here, trying to create a new column (AgeWhenBecamememb) in this view, using the DateOfBirth and MembershipDate values. I just cant get the calculation to work

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TO_DATE()` function to supply your own date format.  For example:

```
select to_date('01/05/1975','dd/mm/yyyy') as DateOfBirth
     , to_date('01/09/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') as MembershipDate
     , FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date('01/09/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('01/05/1975','dd/mm/yyyy'))/12) AS AgeWhenBecameMemb
from dual;
```

For your specific data:

```
select FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date(MembershipDate,'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date(DateOfBirth,'dd/mm/yyyy'))/12) AS AgeWhenBecameMemb
from dual;
```

The syntax you're trying to use (ANSI date literals) is described here:
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Per the documentation:

> The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and must be specified
>   in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.  Alternatively you can specify an Oracle date value, as in the following example:
>   TO_DATE('98-DEC-25 17:30','YY-MON-DD HH24:MI')

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everybody's input. Following taking on your responses, i've got this column to work, like this -

(select floor(TO_CHAR(MembershipDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), TO_CHAR(DateOfBirth, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) /12) AS AGE_OF_CONSUMER from dual) AS AgeWhenBecameMemb

The fields in use for the comparision were in date format already.

Thank you.